# Need bash script to watch Directories and perform actions on new files and modified files

Tags: bash, shell, vim, inotify

I want to watch `mydirectory/`

I created `inot.sh` and ran it in the background as `# ./inot.sh &`

Here's the first version of the script `inot.sh` that I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash    

inotifywait -m -e create,modify --exclude '\*.swp?$' . |
while read dir ev file; do
        cp "$file" inotfiles/"$file"
done
```

Note: the exclude pattern is supposed to exclude vim swap files but doesn't seem to be working yet.

If any file is created (or changed), I want the whole file copied to a storage folder. For now I'm focusing on `create,modify` just to see if I can get anything at all to work correctly.

At this point, FTP uploads seem to work correctly. Using the command line to `touch` a file copies the empty file. But then using `vim` to edit it results in a bunch of problems.

I edited an existing file in vim and did not change it. When I entered the file, I get:

```
cp: cannot stat `.zzzzzoo.txt.swx': No such file or directory
~
~
~
~
~
```

It looks like the first line is part of the file, but it's not. It's inotify interfering with the vim viewer. Upon exit, everything looks normal.

But sometimes I get that same `cp` error message on exit from vim.

If I edit the file and exit with write to file, I get:

Upon exit from vim, I get:

```
~
~
~
~
~
~
"zzzzzoo.txt" cp: cannot stat `4913': No such file or directory
"zzzzzoo.txt" 1L, 11C written
[root@server mydirectory]# cp: cannot stat `.zzzzzoo.txt.swp': No such file or direc
tory
```

1st part with tildes is from vim.

```
"somefile.txt" cp: cannot stat `4913': No such file or directory
"somefile.txt" 7L, 129C written
```

EDIT: adding 1 more error I forget to mention

When I open the copied file in vim, I get a notice that vim found a swap file for the same file name.

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "inotfiles/.somefile.txt.swp"
```

etc, etc.

```
Swap file "inotfiles/.somefile.txt.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

// End edited section

So I know I might be able to fix this problem by properly excluding vim swap files, but it seems to me that the larger question is "Why are cp errors going to stdout and how to stop them?" I should pipe them somewhere else probably.

Also I need a way to prevent an infinite while loop. Is there any other way to write that section?

Comment: The error messages are going to stderr (which, as its name implies, is the file descriptor typically used for error messages). You can redirect errors to /dev/null by running `command 2> /dev/null` (or to file with `command 2> some_file`).

Comment: @larsks thanks. But why did you delete your answer? There is another thing I'm confused also. I had thought I specified "--format %f" to get the filename only as output, but I didn't. And yet somehow the `cp` command still worked on the `inotifywait` output. When I add in the format option, it actually stops working. I get error `cp: omitting directory [backtick]./'` Do you know why that is?

Comment: I deleted the answer because `vim` operates in a mode that means that simply watching for `close_write` events actually won't work.  I figured it was getting too involved.

Comment: Well I tested it and it actually does seem to be working. I am still getting swapfile errors but the inotifywait | cp works.

Comment: If I can make sure my regex excludes swap files, I think that will help somewhat, no?

Comment: Upon write, Vim doesn't save the file: instead it deletes the original and writes another one in its place. I've read elsewhere that the right event for Vim was `close_write` see if that helps you.

Comment: @romainl yes, close_write works great! The only problem I seem to have left is in my regex, which I'll figure out at some point. I think I just need to properly exclude all the temporary files vim creates during editing and it will be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking `inotifywait` to watch out for `vim`'s swap files, why not get `vim` to 
put it's temporary files in a better (less intrusive) location:

For example, how about:

```
mkdir -p ~/tmp/.vim
```

And then in your `.vimrc`

```
set backupdir^=~/tmp/.vim/
set directory^=~/tmp/.vim/
```

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_swap_and_backup_files_from_your_working_directory

Think about it: What if you *do* get your regexes to exclude swap files - and then an `emacs` user joins you and wants to use `emacs` to edit files in the same directory - you'll have a mess of regexes before you know it!